# Let A be a set, and let B = P(A) be the power set of A. Is A ∈ B or A ⊆ B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm genuinely more confused than I previously thought.

Since the power set is the set of all subsets of a set, does that mean the power set is a subset too?

I guess this last question is making me have a lot of second guessing... Thank you for your time.

Comment: $A$ is an element of $B$ since $A \subseteq A$ and $B$ is the powerset of $A$. But, you can also get *both*. Consider $P(\emptyset)$. Then $\emptyset \in P(\emptyset)$ and $\emptyset \subset P(\emptyset)$.

Comment: An interesting side question: under what conditions will $A$ be a subset of $\mathcal{P}(A)$.  Are the only such examples made with nested empty sets?

Comment: No.  The power set is most assuredly not a subset of A. The power set is a set of sets.  It's elements are sets and, in general, not elements of A at all (although there are perverse exceptions).  The *elements* of the power set are sets and *those* are subsets of A but the power set is a different animal than A.  A is a general set with "normal" elements.  P (A) doesn't have "normal" elements but sets.  As $A \subset A: A \in P(A)$ but $A \not \subset P (A) $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This used to confuse me a lot too.

$A$ is an element of $B$.

The types of elements of $A$ and $B$ are fundamentally different; think of $A$ as containing "points", so $A$ is a "set of points".

$B$ does NOT contain points. Therefore it is in some sense a fundamentally different object. $B$ contains "sets of points". Hence $B$ is a "set of sets of points".

As an example:

$$A=\{0,1\}$$

The elements of $A$ are the "points" 0 and 1, just numbers.

$$B = \mathcal{P}(A) = \{ \emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\}    \}$$

The elements of $B$ are "sets of points". Notice that they all have brackets around them; this is NOT the case for the set $A$.

Take care to note that technically speaking $$\{0 \} \not=0$$ for example. Obviously there is a very direct correspondence between them, hence why people tend to ignore the distinction in practice, but it is useful to remember that it is there when one needs to differentiate between "sets of points" and "sets of sets of points".

Comment: I... wow. This actually cleared things up a lot. Thanks so much for the quick reply!

Comment: @envirosuit Note that this distinction can sometimes be muddled a bit. For example, $A$ might contain both points _and_ sets-of-points; in this case, $B={\cal P}(A)$ would contain both sets-of-points and sets-of-sets-of-points. For example, the power set of $\{0,\{0\}\}$ is $\{\,\emptyset,~\{0\},~\{\{0\}\},~\{0,\{0\}\}\,\}$. But this doesn't happen often. (And notice that my example is the same as OP's but with $\{0\}$ instead of $1$.)

Answer (score 1):

A is an element of B. The power set is a set of sets, therefore the sets in it are its elements (and with this, the set A). If it were a subset, then it would need to contain elements of the same type as B (i.e., sets), but it doesn't, since it is itself an element of B.

It helps to think of sets as boxes containing stuff (maybe simple elements, but possibly also other boxes).
If you talk about elements, then you take single elements out of the box. It might be that the thing you just took out of the box is itself a box, but it will be a single element.
If you create a subset, you basically take some of the elements in your set out and put it into a new box. Everyhing in that box then corresponds to the level of the elements in the original box, i.e. the type of elements that are in the subset must be the same as in the original one.

In this case, let's assume that A is a box with some chocolate bars and B is a box with all the possible boxes containing chocolate bars.
Since A is a box of chocolates, it should be an element of the box containing cocolate bars, i.e. B.
If A were a subset of B, this would mean that A is like a smaller version of the box containing boxes with cocolate bars. But A's elements are chocolate bars, you are within a different level, because B's elements are boxes while A's elements are chocolate bars, so A can't be a subset of B (because then, it would have to contain the same "types" of elements as B, namely boxes, but it doesn't), but it is an element of B, because the elements of B are boxes with choclate bars and A is one.
Or, putting it the other way round, if A were a subset of B, then this would mean that we could get a box of chocolate bars by putting some of the stuff in B into a new box, because A's elements are chocolate bars so if it were a subset of B, B should be a set of chocolate bars; but we wouldn't get a box with directly chocolate bars in it (which would be the case if we had A), but rather a box (the subset we just created) containing another box (namely A) containing chocolate bars.

Remark: Of course, imagining B as a box containing all kinds of boxes with chocolate bars is not the very closest equivalent to a power set, since the chocolate bars in B's boxes are all distinct elements, while the elements of B's sets refer to the limited number of entities that are contained in A; but as far as the level of nesting is concerned, this example will do.

May sound like a childish example, but imagining it with boxes to be aware of the type of elements and the "level" of nesting is actually quite helpful.